# If an odd perfect number exists, does it have exactly one prime factor of the form $4a+1$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, perfect-numbers

I know that if an odd perfect number exists it must be of the form $p^kQ^2$ with $\gcd(p, Q) =1$ and $p \equiv k \equiv 1 \mod 4$.

Reading the book *The man who only loved numbers* by Paul Hoffman, it is stated in the second chapter that if there exists an odd perfect number, then it must have exactly one prime divisor of the form $4a+1$.

I haven't found anything about this fact online, nor a way of proving it by myself.

Is it a true statement or a mistake in the book?

Comment: Are you familiar with the divisor-sum function $\sigma$?  If so, you can investigate this claim yourself.

Comment: It seems likely to be a typo to me - that’d be a fairly strong result for it not to be more well known.

Comment: Euler proved that, for an odd perfect number $N$, we have $N=p^k m^2$, where $p\equiv k\equiv 1\bmod 4$, and this $p$ is called "special prime". This is what you also say. However, this $p$ could possibly appear more than once. Books, which are not mathematical lecture notes, are perhaps not so clear with the statements.

Comment: @Dietrich Burde With $p$ appearing more than once do you mean that for that $N$ there could be more than one "special prime", and so the book has a typo, isn't it?

Comment: No, there is only one special prime, but it could have exponent $k=5$, so would appear five times, say. It only says $k\equiv 1\bmod 4$, and not $k=1$. I wouldn't call this a "typo", since there isn't a proposition formulated in the book or is it? What means "stated in the book"?

Comment: What the book says is that, with your notation, the primes in the factorization of $m$ are all congruents with 3 mod 4. If that is true, how can we prove it? Because, proving the theorem of Euler I don't see how it is obvious.

Comment: It is just incorrectly stated in the book (maybe lost somewhere in the translation), the book also mentions it was known by Euler, but what Euler knew was exactly the $N=p^k m^2$ with $p \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$, so it's probably just that.

Comment: I do not understand why there are **three (3)** pending votes to close this question.  Is the context not clear enough?  The poster gave his/her sincere thoughts regarding the problem.  What more could you ask for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $N = p^k m^2$ is an *odd perfect number* with special prime $p$ satisfying $p \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $\gcd(p,m)=1$, and if we let
$$m = \prod_{i=1}^{\omega(m)}{{r_i}^{\alpha_i}}$$
where the $r_i$'s are primes and the $\alpha_i$'s are positive integers, and where $\omega(m)$ is the *number of distinct prime factors* of $m$, then it is **currently unknown** whether $r_i \equiv 3 \pmod 4$, $\forall i$.

It **is known** however, that if $N = p^k m^2$ is an odd perfect number, $m$ has the prime factorization above, and $r_i \equiv 3 \pmod 4$ for all $i$, then $\sigma(p^k)/2$ is a composite number (*P. Starni*, On the Euler’s factor of an odd perfect number, J. Number Theory, **37** (1991), 366-369).

---

**Edit: Added January 09, 2023 - 13:29 PM (Manila time)**

> Chen and Luo proved in [Odd Multiperfect Numbers](https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/9FB2CE0B99D764431E2905FF39F00976/S0004972712000858a.pdf/odd-multiperfect-numbers.pdf) that if $N = p^k m^2$ is an odd perfect number with *special prime* $p$, and if we write
> $$m^2 = \prod_{i}{{p_i}^{2\beta_i}}\prod_{j}{{q_j}^{2\gamma_j}}$$
> where $p_i \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $q_j \equiv 3 \pmod 4$, then
> $$\sigma\left({q_j}^{2\gamma_j}\right) \equiv 1 \pmod 4.$$
> Hence, we have
> $$\sigma(m^2)=\prod_{i}{\sigma\left({p_i}^{2\beta_i}\right)}\prod_{j}{\sigma\left({q_j}^{2\gamma_j}\right)} \equiv \prod_{i}{\left(2\beta_i + 1\right)} \pmod 4.$$
> Clearly, if $\beta_i = 0$ for all $i$, that is
> $$m^2 = \prod_{j}{{q_j}^{2\gamma_j}},$$
> then $\sigma(m^2) \equiv 1 \pmod 4$, and this implies that $p \equiv k \pmod 8$.

Comment: Thank you very much! Sometimes I think some people on this site don't want to understand the questions...

Comment: @Eparoh: Kindly take note of my added edits to this answer from September 10, 2021.

Comment: Thanks for the update! But, I don't see why the last line is true (why we get that $p \equiv k \pmod 8$ from knowing that $\sigma(m^2) \equiv 1 \pmod 4$)

Comment: @Eparoh: Chen and Luo actually proved in [Odd Multiperfect Numbers (Theorem 3.3, page 61)](https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/9FB2CE0B99D764431E2905FF39F00976/S0004972712000858a.pdf/odd-multiperfect-numbers.pdf) that the following biconditionals hold:
$$\sigma(m^2) \equiv 1 \pmod 4 \iff p \equiv k \pmod 8$$
$$\sigma(m^2) \equiv 3 \pmod 4 \iff p \equiv {k+4} \pmod 8$$

Comment: @Eparoh: Dris and San Diego presented an alternative proof for the biconditional
$$\sigma(m^2) \equiv 1 \pmod 4 \iff p \equiv k \pmod 8$$
in [Some modular considerations regarding odd perfect numbers](https://nntdm.net/volume-26-2020/number-2/27-33/).

Comment: Oh, I see. I hadn't checked the sources yet and I thought it was something obvious that I didn't get. Thanks again for all the info!

Comment: My pleasure, @Eparoh!